# How to get the current activity name and the previous activity in android?

Tags: android

I have two activities in my Android app code: `A` and `B`. I have a function `f()` inside `A` which I want to call from `A`'s `onResume()` function only when the previous running activity was `B`, but not in any other cases. How do I know which activity it came from, whether it came from activity `B` or some other activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to decide which activity we came from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953839/how-to-decide-which-activity-we-came-from)

Comment: use start B with startActivityForResult and override onActivityResult in A

Answer (score 4):

Activity A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("Activity_Name","A");
startActivity(intent);
```

If summarize in one line Activity A :

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,B.class).putExtra("Activity_Name","A"));
```

Activity B

```
Log.e("From_Activity",getIntent().getStringExtra("Activity_Name"));
```

Comment: very clever, I believe there could be something a little bit more inside the framework context but this is simple and works